# question with returning an accessor method

Tags: java, string

How would I get the accessor method to return the first letter of a name to be uppercase and the rest in lowercase no matter what was entered?

```
public class Name
{
    private String first;
    private String last;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Name
     */
    public Name(String firstName, String lastName)
    {
        first = firstName;
        last = lastName;
    }

    /**
     * @returns firstName
     */ 
    public String getFirstname()
    {
        return first;       
    }

    /**
     * @returns lastName
     */ 
    public String getLastname()
    {
        return last;  
    }

    /**
     * @returns Fullname
     */ 
    public String getFullname()
    {
        return first + last;
    }

    /**
     * @para new firstname
     */
    public void setFirstname(String firstName)
    {
        first = firstName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't!  Some people have more than one capital letter in their names.

Comment: And I agree with Carl. In your input you should suggest capitalizing it, but you should not change it.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static String capitalizeFirst(String s) {
   return Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(0)) + s.substring(1).toLowerCase();
 }

 public String getFirstname() {
    return capitalizeFirst(first);
 }
```

As the name implies, `capitalizeFirst` capitalizes the first character of a non-empty string, and converts the rest of the string to lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only way I can really think of doing it:

```
last.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + last.substring(1).toLowercase()
```

Comment: And on surrogate pairs. (This is for people with unusual names.)

Comment: Also fails on `null` (which isn't checked for in construction).

Answer (score 0):

Use [StringUtils.capitalize](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.3/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#capitalize(java.lang.String)) from Commons Lang.

Always use the library if it is available, they probably went through all the corner cases that you would only figure out after solving bug after bug.

Comment: But that doesn't ensure that the rest of the name is lower case; it just capitalizes the first and leaves the rest as they are. The OP said "and the rest in lowercase no matter what was entered"